# *** TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given); APIRequestFactory

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I am following the test pattern at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/ and it is not working. I have the view and url as follows

view:

```
class BenchView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'db.views',
    url(r'^bench', BenchView.as_view()),
)
```

tests:

```
class BenchViewTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.request_factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.view = BenchView.as_view()

    def test_results(self):
        request = self.request_factory.get('/base/bench')
        response = BenchView(request)
```

I get

```
*** TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

running the tests. The request should count as one arg, why will this response not work? Thank you

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?  your question seems to indicate that the problem is with `APIRequestFactory` ... But that usage seems consistent with the documentation you linked.  Are you sure the problem isn't with `BenchView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should have:

```
bv = BenchView()
response = bv.get(request)
```

I think that the problem is that `BenchView.__init__` takes no arguments, and you want to be calling `BenchView.get` since it accepts a request as the first positional parameter.

Or perhaps:

```
self.view(request)
```

to be consistent with the linked documentation.

Comment: that works, thank you. seems `as_view` turns it into a function, and I lose the `get` aspect of the class

Comment: Am I missing something, or should that second line be `bv.get(request)`?

Comment: @codyc4321 -- Thanks.  It definitely was supposed to be `bv.get(request)`.

Comment: @JaredGoguen -- You're not missing anything.  My mistake.  Sorry about that.